No internet on wifi router - Issue with switch?
I have the following setup:
MODEM --- WIFI ROUTER ---- SWITCH ---- 4 wired connections to pc, printer, you name it.
Any wifi device that connects to the wifi router, does NOT have internet. When I reset everything, they do.. but after a bit they don't anymore. When I replace the router with another, I have the same issue. When I disconnect the switch from the wifi router, the wifi channels are visible, but am unable to connect to them.
Anyone have any idea what's going on? Am I missing something? Is there something funky going on on the switch?

No. I see the wifi, but when I try to connect, it just spins and spins.. it does not connect. (when I connect the switch again (plus all devices), I CAN connect immediately, but no internet...)
